# xor Boolean algebra simplification

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra

I am doing boolean algebra simplification and got the result of (A.B) xor(C xor D) Does (A.B) xor (C xor D) = (A.B) xor C xor D ?

Answer (score 3):

yes, because XOR is associative

It's also commutative